# How can I dispatch key event in child composable function in jetpack compose? or is there any way to do it?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I created number pad component and I'd like to use it with physical keyboard too.

I tried with 'onKeyEvent' at the NumberPadView(this is used as child view in other screens)

```
Column(
        modifier = modifier.onKeyEvent { event: KeyEvent ->
            Log.d("aos", "event: ${event.type}, ${event.key}, ${event.type == KeyEventType.KeyDown}")
            if (event.type == KeyEventType.KeyDown) {
                when (event.key) {
                    Key.Backspace -> {
                        onKeyDown.invoke("<")
                    }
                    Key.NumPad0, Key.NumPad1, Key.NumPad2, Key.NumPad3, Key.NumPad4, Key.NumPad5, Key.NumPad6, Key.NumPad7, Key.NumPad8, Key.NumPad9 -> {
                        onKeyDown.invoke(event.key.toString())
                    }
                }
            }
            false
        }
    ){
     ....
    }
```

But this doesn't catch anything. Is there anyway to dispatch key event in jetpack compose?

Answer (score 1):

To handle key events in Jetpack Compose, you can use the LocalSoftwareKeyboardController and LocalFocusManager to detect and manage keyboard input. You can utilize onPreviewKeyEvent in combination with the focusRequester to achieve this. Here's an example on how you can handle key events in a child composable function:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun NumberPadView(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, onKeyDown: (String) -> Unit) {
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .focusRequester(focusRequester)
            .onPreviewKeyEvent { event: KeyEvent ->
                if (event.type == KeyEventType.KeyDown) {
                    when (event.key) {
                        Key.Backspace -> {
                            onKeyDown.invoke("<")
                        }
                        Key.NumPad0, Key.NumPad1, Key.NumPad2, Key.NumPad3, Key.NumPad4, Key.NumPad5, Key.NumPad6, Key.NumPad7, Key.NumPad8, Key.NumPad9 -> {
                            onKeyDown.invoke(event.key.toString())
                        }
                    }
                }
                false
            }
    ) {
        // Your number pad content here
    }
}
```

Finally, use the NumberPadView composable function in another composable, and don't forget to request focus for it:

```
@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    // ...
    NumberPadView(onKeyDown = { input ->
        // Handle input from the physical keyboard
        println("Key input: $input")
    })
    // ...
}
```